# Gradle exception with ClassLoaderLogManager on Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: android, tomcat, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm compiling Android APK files with command line in five servers. The five servers has apache tomcat 7 compiling with a .war jsp app (using java) android apks. My .war jsp file uses `gradlew assembleRelease` in command line to compile the apks.

In four of my servers it works perfectly but in my linux server i got a exception.

- Windows Server 2008 -> OK, no exception
- Windows Server 2008 2 -> OK, no exception
- OS X -> OK, no exception
- OX X 2 -> OK, no exception
- Linux -> **Exception**

**I will add the gradle files of my project below the exception text, but i think this problem is not of my gradle files, it works in four of my servers, so i think it is a problem of my linux server apache tomcat config or something**

This is the exception:

```
Could not load Logmanager "org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:186)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:176)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.JavaUtilLoggingConfigurer.configure(JavaUtilLoggingConfigurer.java:36)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingConfigurer.configure(DefaultLoggingConfigurer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.LoggingSystemAdapter.setLevel(LoggingSystemAdapter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.LoggingSystemAdapter.on(LoggingSystemAdapter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager$StartableLoggingSystem.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:173)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:58)
    at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager.start(DefaultLoggingManager.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
```

These are my gradle files:

Main project gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Application module gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:22'
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.launcher"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 10
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("dummy")
            storePassword "dummy"
            keyAlias "dummy"
            keyPassword "dummy"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':capLibrary')
}
```

Library module gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:22'
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 10
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

Comment: are your Tomcat configs identical for all platforms?